# Replace Spring4 DataBinder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'd like to replace/extend the Spring Framework 4 DataBinder. I know there are other concepts like Converter, PropertyEditors and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

For my case I don't want to use one of them. Since the Databinder makes up about 95% of the function i need and i don't want to implement it again.

In fact i want to subclass ServletRequestDataBinder and overwrite addBindValues()

I can't figure out how how to replace the databinder. If possible i don't want to replace anything else.

Does anyone know how to do this in spring 4 using javaconfig?

Comment: What is the 5% that it doesn't cover. Although it is possible it would require to override some core classes and loosing the benefit of auto configuration.

Comment: i want to support Interfaces in @ModelAttributes. I plan to submit a field called type which should indicate the interface implementation. The type parameter should be evaluated first as i dont want to bind the other values manually (or create an object that has all attributes). I also didn't found a composite property editor which would get access to the other parameters.

Comment: Why not simply use a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method for that? That constructs the object needed for binding. Looks like that should work and would be a lot easier then overriding some core spring classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use `@InitBinder` (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) for most things. Does that not work for you (you can't return a new binder).

Comment: As far as i can tell right now. No, this is why I am asking. See comment to question.